# Буква Ё в произведениях А.С. Пушкина

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография, фонетика

Здравствуйте! В учебнике "Русская словесность" для 5 класса (издательство "Атамура", г. Алматы, 2010 год) в "Сказке о попе и о работнике его Балде" А.С. Пушкина встречается следующее написание: "Ты, бес*е_нок, ещ*е_ молоден*ё_к, / Со мною тягаться слаб*е*н_ё*к". При этом больше нигде в тексте учебника _Ё_ не встречается. Насколько мне известно, Пушкин был противником этой буквы. Оправданно и уместно ли подобное написание? Может, так на самом деле произносятся эти слова?... Если Вы укажете источник, на который можно сослаться, буду очень признательна.
Румбах Е.В., учитель русского языка и литературы

Answer (score 4):

насчет буквы ё - есть уже известная классика:

```
В марте страна передохнет от морозов.
```

видите, как отсутствие всего двух точек влияет на смысл... :)

Comment: практически как "казнить нельзя помиловать" )))

Answer (score 2):

Е или Ё в суффиксах енек/онек?
 Русская грамматика-80 :

> § 668. Суффикс -енек/-онек. Прилагательные с суф. -енек/-онек (фонемат. **|eн'a1к|/ |он'a1к|**; с чередованием |к - к'|, гласная |a1| беглая), употребляющиеся только в краткой форме, обозначают умеренно высокую степень качества: слабенек, далеконек, строгонек, крутенек, хмельненек, тяжеленек, простенек; Речка, речка невеличка, Собой глубоконька (нар. песня); **Ты, бесёнок, еще молоденек, Со мною тягаться слабенек** (Пушк.); Солоненька, брат, колбаса-то! - говорит он (С.-Щ.). Морф -енек выступает после парно-мягких согласных (парно-твердые, кроме заднеязычных, чередуются перед ним с мягкими); морф -онек - после твердых заднеязычных. **Ударение на первом слоге суффикса**: гордЕнек, долгОнек.
>
> Слова этого типа принадлежат к устарелой разговорной лексике. Продуктивность типа ограничена образованиями от исконно русских качественных прилагательных, характерными для литературы, ориентированной на старую народную речь и фольклор.

Русская пословица (*Еще молод**е**нек : доживешь до д**е**нег*) не оставляет сомнений в произношении слова (и суффикса).

Answer (score 1):

Дкмаю, что там правильно. Во всяком случае - фонетически. Молоденёк и слабенёк - краткие формы прилагательных молоденький и слабенький. Сейчас бы их скорее произнесли с ударением на третьем слоге с конца, но при Пушкине, да ещё при передаче народной речи... Думаю, так оно и мыслилось Пушкиным. А в бесенок народное ударение на "ок" вполне возможно.

По поводу того, что Пушкин был противником буквы Ё, хотелось бы попобробнее, я о таком не слышал. Но даже если что-о такое и было, здесь-то вопрос не в букве, а в произношении.

Comment: Спасибо большое! И всё-таки на что можно сослаться? Может, какие-то словари? В имеющихся в наличии не встречала )

Comment: Попробуйте разыскать словарь языка Пушкина. Удостовериться, что там что-то есть, не могу. Этот словарь несколько лет назад у меня был в электронном варианте, но погиб.

Comment: В бумажном  варианте  словаря  языка  Пушкина  эта  фраза  написана  с  буквой  "е".  В  самом  словаре  буква  "ё"  присутствует:"...всё  туже,  туже..."  Т.4,  стр.161.  Но  на  той  же  странице  "...в  нем  не  слабеет  воля  злая...".  Что  здесь:  произносили  так  или  "ё"  не  поставили ?

Comment: Или  в  самом  словаре  буква  "ё"  используется  только  там,  где  иное  прочтение  изменяет  смысл  слова - "всё"  и  "все".  Хотя  из  контекста  "...стал  их  обвивать  около  руки  сначала  слабо,  а  потом  всё  туже,  туже..."  и  так  ясно,  что  надо  писать  "ё".

Comment: А  может  звук, обозначенный  буквой  Ё  быть  в  безударном  положении ?  Сказать  -  "Да  ты  слабенёк  против  него !" -  можно,  но  ударение  упадёт  на  последний  слог.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Это  цитата  из  публикации  в  альманахе  "Сын  отечества"  за  1840 год  (  в  формате  ДЕЖАВЮ  ).  Действительно  ни  одной  буквы  "ё".  И  в  других  дореволюционных  изданиях  так  же.  Вопрос:  откуда  появилось  "ё"  в  современном  издании  ?  Ещё  вопрос:  звук,  обозначаемый  буквой  "ё" ,  не  прозносился,  или  буква  "ё"  игнорировалась ?

Comment: >[Совѣтник:] Однако она **всіˆо** тебѣ вѣрна пребывает. Фнв. Бриг. 95. [Степан:] Еще она слава Богу **всіˆо** в добром здоровьи. Княж. Сбит. 270.  
(взято из ФЭБ, Словарь РЯ 18 в.)

Некоторые авторы пользовались подобным диграфом, но позже на это дело плюнули и везде писали обыкновенную *е*, то же самое наблюдаем и в наше время : буква ё никому не нужна. 
В Словаре 1806-22 еще так приведено написание слова *белёк*, а в 1847 уже просто - *белек*...
![Белёк](http://slovari.pro/russkie/slovari/tolkovie/akademii-1806-1822_vol-1/slovar-akad-alf-1/185.html)

Comment: По-моему  очень  нужна.  А  как  произносили-то ?  Где  ударение  ставить ?  Белёк  или  белек:  слово  не  очень  распростанённое.  Не  бесенок.  Не  зря  же  Карамзин  предложил  эту  букву.  Мы  говорим  бесёнок, а  с  какого  времени ?  Может  в  начале  19  века  говорили  бесенок ?  Если бы  буква  "ё"  не  игнорировалась,  мы  бы  знали,  когда  изменилось  произношение.

Comment: В словарях 19 века всегда можно было найти ударение, но не букву **ё**)

Comment: А  произносили  как ?  Дифтонг  "io"  уже  был ?

Comment: Был, еще с 18 века.
http://russian7.ru/2013/11/7-uvlekatelnyx-manyovrov-bukvy-yo/

Comment: Умнее  товарища  Сталина  никого  не  оказалось. Текст  по  этой  ссылке  интересный,  но  не  очень  серьёзный.  Полностью  на  мой  вопрос  не  отвечает.  Получается  в  русском  языке  звук  есть,  но  в  литературном  русском  его  обозначать  не  принято.  А  произносить  принято ?  Или  так  и  говорили:  белек, бесенок.  А  простонародье  говорило  белёк,  бесёнок  и  т.п.  Но  простонародье  писательством  не  увлекалось  и  орфоэпических ( и  орфографических )  норм  не  устанавливало.  Если  писали,  как  говорили,  тогда  и  проблемы  нет.  И  для  нас  это  архаизм.